# How to get Choppiness from 1 hr timeframe on 1 min chart?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I made adjustments to the original Choppiness Index indicator to fetch data from the 1-hour timeframe while on a 1-minute chart. However, the output is incorrect and unstable compared to the original indicator set on a 1-hour timeframe on a 1-minute chart. Despite changing all the variables' formulas to fetch 1-hour data, it's not functioning as expected. I'm unsure what I'm missing here.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Choppiness Index mtf", shorttitle="CHOP mtf")

length = input.int(14, minval=1)
// Fetching 60-minute timeframe data
atr_1hr = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", ta.atr(1))
highest_1hr = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", ta.highest(length))
lowest_1hr = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", ta.lowest(length))

// Calculate Choppiness Index
ci = 100 * math.log10(math.sum(atr_1hr, length) / (highest_1hr - lowest_1hr)) / math.log10(length)

offset = input.int(0, "Offset", minval=-500, maxval=500)
plot(ci, "CHOP", color=#2962FF, offset=offset)

band1 = hline(61.8, "Upper Band", color=#787B86, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
band0 = hline(38.2, "Lower Band", color=#787B86, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
fill(band1, band0, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="Background")
```